# Регулярное выражение вида (ао|ап)(здесь название)(ао|ап)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, как всегда прошу вашей помощи. Помогите составить универсальный шаблон.

Имеется список строк:

1. ап ОАО "ТГК-2"
2. ао ОАО "ТГК-2"
3. "ТГК-2" ап
4. "ТГК-2" ао
5. ТГК-2 ап
6. ТГК-2 ао
7. Сбербанк России ОАО ао
8. ОАО Сбербанк России ао
9. "КрасныйОктябрь" ОАО - ао
10. ОАО "КрасныйОктябрь" - ао

Вариаций самого названия может быть много, мне конкретно нужно что-то вроде такого плана:

```
(ао|ап)(здесь название)(ао|ап)
```

такой шаблон нужен, чтобы в дальнейшем отпилить **ао** или **ап**, в зависимости где это словосочетание будет находится, задача в том, чтобы получить только само название без **ао** или **ап** и без символа **"-"**

Я придумал такой шаблон, но он что-то не совсем хочет работать:

```
^(ао|ап)*(\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s)(ао|ап)$*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой шаблон:

`/^(ао\s|ап\s)?(.*?)(\s-)?(\sао|\sап)?$/m`

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось, немного допилил: 
^(ао|ап)?(\s-\s)?(.*?)(\s-)?(\sао|\sап)?$

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```
 ^(ао|ап)(.*)$|^(.*)(ао|ап)$
```

Comment: да, можно и так, и вам спасибо, за участие!